# LibGDX how to remove PointLight that is attached a destroyed Body

Tags: libgdx

I have this code:

```
@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    fa = contact.getFixtureA();
    fb = contact.getFixtureB();

    if (fa == null || fb == null) return;
    if (fa.getUserData() == null || fb.getUserData() == null) return;

    final Body toRemove = contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getType() == BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody ?
            contact.getFixtureA().getBody() :
            contact.getFixtureB().getBody();
    Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            world.destroyBody(toRemove);
        }
    });

}
```

It removes the FA body, but this body have a pointlight attached.
I want to remove this PointLight attached.
I have no idea how to do this :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep a list of all your `Light`s, then when you come to destroy the `Body` `toRemove` you  can first iterate over that list and see if there are any `Light`s that are associated with that `Body`.

```
public class SomeClass {

  private List<Light> lights;

  ...

@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
  fa = contact.getFixtureA();
  fb = contact.getFixtureB();

  if (fa == null || fb == null) return;
  if (fa.getUserData() == null || fb.getUserData() == null) return;

  final Body toRemove = contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getType() ==     BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody ?
    contact.getFixtureA().getBody() :
    contact.getFixtureB().getBody();
  Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            Light light = null;
            for(Light l : lights) {
              if(l.getBody() == toRemove) 
                light = l;
            }
            if (light != null) {
              light.remove();
              lights.remove(light);
            }
            world.destroyBody(toRemove);
        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: Thx, helped a lot, i made little changes in your code, and works very well...